# How to listen `disconnect` event in Java NIO?

Tags: java, nio

In java NIO server, we can register `SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT`, listen and read `channel` from `selector.select()` and `selector.selectedKeys()`.

But how to listen to the 'disconnected' event?

Trying `channel.read()` and catching the exception is a way if the channel has been read from the selector. But what should I do if the channel has not been read from the selector any more?

Comment: Define 'disconnected event'. Are you asking about orderly or disorderly disconnects? And BTW are you asking about NIO or Netty?

Comment: @user207421 `disconnect` means underlying tcp/ip connection was broken (such as tcp-keepalive broken).

Comment: Well it isn't a selector event. There are only read and write events. You will get one of them, after which the corresponding operation will throw an exception.

Answer (score -2):

A disconnect is a read event with an error.

Comment: Or a read event where `read()` returns -1.

Comment: @benson23 Yes it does. Possibly a wrong answer, but an answer.

Comment: More often than -1 I get an exception "An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host". Both are possible, but in any case I get a read event.